# Split XML File with Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm new on the subject, but I read a lot of solutions regarding this topic. Unfortunately they were all on a very simple case that I can not readjust to my problem. My XML document is structured as:

```
<messagge>
  <heading>
    <context>
      <forniture>
        <fornitureHeading>..other tags..</fornitureHeading>
        <document>
          ...other tags...
        </document>
        <document>
         ...
        </document>
        ...
      </forniture>
    </context>
  </heading>
</messagge>
```

I need to create one new XML file foreach `<document>` but i need to maintain all the information above(tags - attribute - and whatever) like this:

**document1.xml**

```
<messagge>
  <heading>
    <context>
      <forniture>
        <fornitureHeading>..other tags..</fornitureHeading>
        <document1>
          ...other tags...
        </document1>
      </forniture>
    </context>
  </heading>
</messagge>
```

**document2.xml**

```
<messagge>
  <heading>
    <context>
      <forniture>
        <fornitureHeading>..other tags..</fornitureHeading>
        <document2>
          ...other tags...
        </document2>
      </forniture>
    </context>
  </heading>
</messagge>
```

an so....
I tried this script
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057161/3116904

```
File input = new File(pathFile);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Message/Context/Forniture/Document", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

int itemsPerFile = 1;
int fileNumber = 0;
Document currentDoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Node rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("Message");

File currentFile = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER+fileNumber+".xml");
for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true);
    rootNode.appendChild(imported);

    if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) {
        writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);

        rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("Messaggio");
        currentFile = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER+(++fileNumber)+".xml");
    }
}
```

The problem wiht this script is that it write in the new file only the `<document>` tag, and not also the parent tag.
Now is clear and equal to the linked one, but I tried some solution for write also upper nodes, add them to a NodeList and then tried to append at this every `<document>` node, but didn't work.
Any suggestion would be valued.
Thanks

Additional Info:

-I can't change XML Structure

-I need to maintain the same structure( `<document1><document2>` are just for explain better my situation)

Comment: do you have an xsd that this XML conforms to ?

Comment: Yes, but (i don't know if is a matter) is a complex xsd, with a lot of file that compose it

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to use XJC , generate Java Classes and then marshall/unmarshall using JAXB. A pretty straightforward tutorial is here : http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/

Comment: i just have classes created by XJC and do the unmarshal of the whole document for other computation. Now for do the marshal of a single new XML i need to unmarshal the document another time(for create a duplicate that not references the other object) remove the documents list and then add each time a single document and marshal it. I wrote the code(very simple) for this solution, and it's work, but Unfortunatly this operation(especially the unmarshalling) require a lot of time and resource for big file, so i'm looking for an alternative solution

Comment: @Gyanapriya if you know any better solution than to make a second unmarshalling it would be valued

Comment: Does spawning a new async thread for unmarshalling each separate file sound like a good alternative ? I don't have any alternatives other than to try and think of ways to speed up existing code.

Answer (score 0):

How big do you anticipate your documents to be?
Do you have control of the xml, like can you change its structure? 
it doesnt look semantically right (document within the header?)

And by splitting the file, do you still expect to maintain the previous xml structure? `<document1>, <document2>,` dont sound right.
or what is the purpose of your splitting the file

is ok either way, this is just further information that can help people give you a better solution.

Comment: Andrea, i dont understand the down vote? this questions are needed to help you...like now jaxb option is good if the files are not that big

Comment: Maybe someone downvoted because that should have been a comment instead of an answer. I'm just a passerby...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way but I do not like it at all, because i need to create a temporary copy of the whole XML file for each `<document>` inside. This is because i stupidly  forgot a simply but basic thing: document, element, node, class... are object!! and the copy is a [Shallow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy).

The solution is related to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558709/getchildnodes-giving-unexpected-result)

```
public static void separaDichiarazioniXML(String pathINFile, String pathOUTFile) throws Exception{

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder domparser = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = domparser.parse(new File(pathINFile));

    Node messaggio = doc.getFirstChild();
    Node contenuto = null;

    boolean intestazione = false;
    for(int i=0; i<messaggio.getChildNodes().getLength();i++){
        if(messaggio.getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            if(intestazione){
                contenuto = messaggio.getChildNodes().item(i);
                intestazione = false;
                for(int j=0; j<contenuto.getChildNodes().getLength();j++){
                    if(contenuto.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                        NodeList doc730 = doc.getElementsByTagName("m730:Documento730");
                        for(int k=0; k<doc730.getLength(); k++){
                    //NEED TO CREATE ANOTHER COPY OF THE DOCUMENT FOR NOT CHANGE DATA IN THE CURRENT MEMORY REFERENCE WHERE I'M WORKING
                    //USING ALL INDEXES FOUND
                            Document docTmp = domparser.parse(new File(pathINFile));
                            Node messaggioTmp = docTmp.getFirstChild();
                            Node contenutoTmp = messaggioTmp.getChildNodes().item(i);
                            Node fornituraTmp = contenutoTmp.getChildNodes().item(j);
                            NodeList doc730Tmp = docTmp.getElementsByTagName("m730:Documento730");
                            for(int t=0; t<doc730.getLength(); t++){
                                if(k!=t){   
                                    fornituraTmp.removeChild(doc730Tmp.item(t));
                                }
                            }
                            writeToFile(messaggioTmp, new File(pathOUTFile+"doc_"+k+".xml"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                intestazione = true;
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

now, or I did not understand the behavior of DOMparsing in Java, or this is a problem that can not be solved at low computational costs. I definitely prefer the solution that I had already implemented: the unmarshalling and marshalling, as available to me, thanks to XJC, the object structure of my XML document. 
This is mi previous solution

```
//structure for temporary copy
JAXBContext jcc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messaggio.class);
Unmarshaller uu = jcc.createUnmarshaller();
Messaggio mIntestazione = (Messaggio) uu.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(bb),
                    "UTF-8"));
//clean temporary structure documents
mIntestazione.getContenuto().getFornitura().getDocumento().clear();
//structure for elaboration
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messaggio.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Messaggio m = (Messaggio) u.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(bb),
                    "UTF-8"));

Fornitura f = m.getContenuto().getFornitura();

for (Documento doc : f.getDocumento()) {
    String fileOut = nomeFile.substring(0, nomeFile.lastIndexOf("."))+"_"+doc.getIdentificativo();
    //add the current elaboration doc at temporary structure for print it in a separate file
    mIntestazione.getContenuto().getFornitura().getDocumento().add(doc);
    JAXBContext jout = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messaggio.class);
    Marshaller mx = jout.createMarshaller();
    mx.setProperty(mx.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, new Boolean(true));
    mx.marshal(mIntestazione, new File(_PathOut_+fileOut+_XML));
    //clean temporary structure
    mIntestazione.getContenuto().getFornitura().getDocumento().clear();
}
```

What do you think about this problem? 
if you have a suggestion to improve my code, it will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of doing the splitting with [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net) and [XPath](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/34045), I used XPath to navigate the document structure... and an element Fragment is designated by its offset and value...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class simpleSplit {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\message.xml", true)) //namespace awareness disabled
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn), ap2=new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/messagge/heading/context/forniture/document"); //first xpath
        FastLongBuffer fib= new FastLongBuffer();// grab all the fragments
        int i=0;long l1=0,l2=0,l3=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            fib.append(vn.getElementFragment());
        }   
        ap2.selectXPath("/messagge/heading/context/forniture"); //second xpath
        i=ap2.evalXPath();
        if(vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD,"fornitureHeading")){
            l1= vn.getElementFragment();
            vn.toElement(VTDNav.P);
        }
        l2 = vn.getContentFragment();
        for (int j=0;j<fib.size();j++){
            xm.insertAfterHead(vn,l1);
            xm.removeContent((int)(l2),(int)(l2>>32));
            l3= fib.longAt(j);
            xm.insertBeforeTail(vn,l3);
            xm.output("d:\\xml\\outMessage"+(j+1)+".xml");
            xm.reset();
        }
    }
}
```