# Different results on java DOM XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, dom

I used DOM parser for parsing an XML file. I used a formatted xml and not-formatted xml file as input.

**Formatted**

```
<students>
    <student>
        <name>Vicky</name>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
    </student>
</students>
```

**Not Formatted**

```
<students><student><name>Vicky</name></student><student><name>John</name></student></students>
```

When run the below code to get the child elements I got different results.

```
public class XmlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("testFile.xml")));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Element mainEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodes = mainEle.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("No.of Childs = " + nodes.getLength());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results Are;**

**For Formatted XML** : 5

**For Not Formatted** : 2

Why there is different results for a xml with same content?

Comment: Please post the code you used so that we may test it ourselves locally.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : added the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558709/getchildnodes-giving-unexpected-result

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace that creates the formatting consists of `text()` nodes. They're missing in the unformatted XML.

In the unformatted document, there are 1 `student` children of the root. In the formatted one, there are 3 more `text()` nodes: before the students, between them, and after them.

Verified in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open file.xml ;
for /students/node() echo name() xsh:if(self::text(), 'text', '') ;

 text
student
 text
student
 text
```

Comment: Perhaps, but can you explain the observed results of `5` and `2`?